# How to logs result to file AND display when using W10 CMD.EXE?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, command-line-arguments

When using Windows 10 command prompt, i know i can log the results to file by doing this :

`dir c:\ > results.txt`

But problem is, doing this , the results are NOT displayed on the screen.

Is there a way to use both ways at the same time ? I want the results to be displayed in real time AND log to file.

Comment: CMD is quite simple minded. Run CMD twice or invest in Power Shell programming.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is the UNIX `tail` command.  [The UnxUtils](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) package contains this command.  As @John points out, powershell can do this out of the box but if you are looking to do what you are already doing without re-writing and re-learning, this is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to first write it to the textfile and then displaying it by using the following command:

```
dir > a.txt | type a.txt
```

It may have problems including the first few lines. If you need those too, you can use:

```
dir > a.txt & type a.txt
```

The only downside is that if the dir command takes a long time, its going to take a while before you see the output.

If dir is really long and you want the output to take place at the same time, powershell is a better tool in that case. Keep in mind, that if you do display the output and log it at the same time, the displaying will cause a slowdown as well.

Comment: Thanks but problem is, the command is quite long, some hours... i'd like to see while it performs

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest and (in my opinion) best option on a Windows machine is to use [Baretail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/), and tail the log file.